# An error is occuring with actionscript I am trying to embed into my flash file

Tags: flash, animation, flash-cs5

Basically I'm making a swaying grass effect and this error comes up and I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 19  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method duplicateMovieClip.

Scene1-Actions frame 1:

```
 import flash.display.MovieClip;

function duplicate(name:MovieClip, amount:Number):void
{
    for(var i = 1; i<= amount; i++)
    {
        duplicateMovieClip(name, name+"_"+i, i);
    }


}
duplicate(grass_mc, 50);
```

grass-Action Frames 1

```
onClipEvent(load)
{
    this.height= random(70)+5
    this.width = random(15)+5
    this._x = random(Stage.width);
    this.gotoAndPlay(random(20));

}
```

Comment: What version of action script are you using?

Answer (score 1):

So basically you need the good ol' `duplicateMovieClip` method from as2 in as3. There are a few ways to achieve similar results, but first of all, I'm going to suggest you read some tutorial on **Classes** and **Objects** and **OOP** in general for ActionScript3, for example [this one from kirupa](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/as3/classes_as3_pg1.htm).

Once you read that you should be more than capable to do the trick, but here is a walkthrough anyways, trying to keep things simple:

Go to your **Library**, right-click on your grass **Symbol**, select **Properties** and check `Export for ActionScript` and `Export in frame 1`. Write `Grass` as the **Class name**, leave the **Base Class** as it is (it will say *flash.display.MovieClip*. You'll get a prompt saying that the class couldn't be found, for now it's OK. Done this, every time you create a Grass object with the line `var my_mc:MovieClip = new Grass();` and you `addChild` it to the stage (or to any movieclip that is already on the stage) you are creating a "copy"  of the original grass movieclip.

So, for example, this code will create 50 instances of a Grass movieclip:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

createGrass(50);

function createGrass(amount:uint):void
{
    var grass_mc:MovieClip;
    for(var i:uint = 1; i<= amount; i++)
    {
        grass_mc = new Grass();
        grass_mc.name = "grass_mc"+i;

        initGrass(grass_mc);
        addChildAt(grass_mc,i);
    }

}

//grass-Action Frames 1
function initGrass(mc:MovieClip):void
{
    mc.height= Math.random()*70+5;
    mc.width = Math.random()*15+5;
    mc.x = Math.random()*stage.width;
    mc.gotoAndPlay(Math.ceil(Math.random()*20));

}
```

Also, the code you labelled as **grass-Action Frames 1** is all in as2, I converted it to as3 and wrote it as a function on your timeline for cleanliness, so you'll need to remove it from inside your grass movieclip.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The duplicateMovieClip method is from ActionScript2 and it is now deprecated within ActionScript 3.

You can no longer ‘duplicate’ a movie clip, but there are a few ways to achieve the same outcome. If you’re not confident with creating a new class that will create multiple instances of your object, take a look at [this link](http://flash.lillegutt.com/?p=55) it should help explain the process.

Comment: Would there be any chance of an example with the new methods? Sorry , I'm quite lost at the moment!

Comment: The link provided contains good code samples, are you lost at a specific point?